# Как сделать бегущие картинки jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет! Как сделать бегущие картинки как на сайте http://www.gain-dragon.ru/ в самом низу увидите надпись Наши достижение а ниже будет карусель. Есть ли готовый исходный код?

Comment: Готовый код есть, и он в свободном доступе на сайте http://www.gain-dragon.ru/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<marquee></marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если откроете консоль на этом сайте там все видно. 
position: relative и анимация свойства left
Реализация конечно не совсем удачная, так как в какой-то момент набор картинок перепрыгивает на исходную позицию. 
Реализовано через библиотеку [jQuery.crawlLine.js](http://code.google.com/p/freesmi/source/browse/trunk/content/js/jquery.crawlLine.js?r=62)

Answer (score 1):

[Попробуй слайдер](http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону [jQuery scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html)
Немного подправить верстку, настроить autoscroll и будет то что надо, и как сказал [@Нурбек Абулгазин](/users/2804/%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD) картинки не будут перепрыгивать в самое начало